# Updating multiple rows in a database using PHP, but only the first three rows are updated

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, sql-update

In my website I retrieve information from a database, manipulate the information using a form, and then update the respective rows in the database with the new information. I do this for 20 rows, using identical code barring the variable names for each (or so I think), though only the first 3 rows in the database are updated.

Here is the html form for the first 4 rows of the 20:

```
<form name="bpl_scores" action="db_scores_bpl.php" method="post">
    Arsenal <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="arsenal" value="arsenal_win" id="arsenal_win" checked>
    Win</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="arsenal" value="arsenal_draw" id="arsenal_draw">
    Draw</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="arsenal" value="arsenal_lose" id="arsenal_lose">
    Lose</label>

  <br>
  <br>
    Aston Villa <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="astonvilla" value="astonvilla_win" id="astonvilla_win" checked>
    Win</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="astonvilla" value="astonvilla_draw" id="astonvilla_draw">
    Draw</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="astonvilla" value="astonvilla_lose" id="astonvilla_lose">
    Lose</label>

  <br>
  <br>
    Burnley <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="burnley" value="burnley_win" id="burnley_win" checked>
    Win</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="burnley" value="burnley_draw" id="burnley_draw">
    Draw</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="burnley" value="burnley_lose" id="burnley_lose">
    Lose</label>

  <br>
  <br>
    Chelsea <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="chelsea" value="chelsea_win" id="chelsea_win" checked>
    Win</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="chelsea" value="chelsea_draw" id="chelsea_draw">
    Draw</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="chelsea" value="chelsea_lose" id="chelsea_lose">
    Lose</label>

  <br>
  <br>
    Crystal Palace <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="crystalpalace" value="crystalpalace_win" id="crystalpalace_win" checked>
    Win</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="crystalpalace" value="crystalpalace_draw" id="crystalpalace_draw">
    Draw</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="crystalpalace" value="crystalpalace_lose" id="crystalpalace_lose">
    Lose</label>
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" formaction="db_scores_bpl.php" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is the php code for the first 4 rows in the `db_scores_bpl.php` page:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','pass','database');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bpl_teams WHERE team='Arsenal' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$arsenal_wins = $row['wins'];
$arsenal_draws = $row['draws'];
$arsenal_losses = $row['losses'];
$arsenal_score = $row['points'];
$arsenal_played = $row['played'];

$arsenal = $_POST['arsenal'];
if ($arsenal == "arsenal_win") {
    $arsenal_score = $arsenal_score + 3;
    $arsenal_wins = $arsenal_wins + 1;
    $arsenal_played = $arsenal_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$arsenal_played', wins='$arsenal_wins', points='$arsenal_score' WHERE team = 'Arsenal'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}
elseif ($arsenal == "arsenal_draw") {
    $arsenal_score = $arsenal_score + 1;
    $arsenal_draws = $arsenal_draws + 1;
    $arsenal_played = $arsenal_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$arsenal_played', draws='$arsenal_draws', points='$arsenal_score' WHERE team = 'Arsenal'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}
else {
    $arsenal_losses = $arsenal_losses + 1;
    $arsenal_played = $arsenal_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$arsenal_played', losses='$arsenal_losses' WHERE team = 'Arsenal'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}

$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','pass','database');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bpl_teams WHERE team='Aston Villa' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$astonvilla_wins = $row['wins'];
$astonvilla_draws = $row['draws'];
$astonvilla_losses = $row['losses'];
$astonvilla_score = $row['points'];
$astonvilla_played = $row['played'];    

$astonvilla = $_POST['astonvilla'];
if ($astonvilla == "astonvilla_win") {
    $astonvilla_score = $astonvilla_score + 3;
    $astonvilla_wins = $astonvilla_wins + 1;
    $astonvilla_played = $astonvilla_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$astonvilla_played', wins='$astonvilla_wins', points='$astonvilla_score' WHERE team = 'Aston Villa'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}
elseif ($astonvilla == "astonvilla_draw") {
    $astonvilla_score = $astonvilla_score + 1;
    $astonvilla_draws = $astonvilla_draws + 1;
    $astonvilla_played = $astonvilla_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$astonvilla_played', draws='$astonvilla_draws', points='$astonvilla_score' WHERE team = 'Aston Villa'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();
}
else {
    $astonvilla_losses = $astonvilla_losses + 1;
    $astonvilla_played = $astonvilla_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$astonvilla_played', losses='$astonvilla_losses' WHERE team = 'Aston Villa'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}

$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','pass','database');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bpl_teams WHERE team='Burnley' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$burnley_wins = $row['wins'];
$burnley_draws = $row['draws'];
$burnley_losses = $row['losses'];
$burnley_score = $row['points'];
$burnley_played = $row['played'];   

$burnley = $_POST['burnley'];
if ($burnley == "burnley_win") {
    $burnley_score = $burnley_score + 3;
    $burnley_wins = $burnley_wins + 1;
    $burnley_played = $burnley_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$burnley_played', wins='$burnley_wins', points='$burnley_score' WHERE team = 'Burnley'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}
elseif ($burnley == "burnley_draw") {
    $burnley_score = $burnley_score + 1;
    $burnley_draws = $burnley_draws + 1;
    $burnley_played = $burnley_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$burnley_played', draws='$burnley_draws', points='$burnley_score' WHERE team = 'Burnley'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}
else {
    $burnley_losses = $burnley_losses + 1;
    $burnley_played = $burnley_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$burnley_played', losses='$burnley_losses' WHERE team = 'Burnley'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}

$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','pass','database');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bpl_teams WHERE team='Chelsea' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$chelsea_wins = $row['wins'];
$chelsea_draws = $row['draws'];
$chelsea_losses = $row['losses'];
$chelsea_score = $row['points'];
$chelsea_played = $row['played'];   

$chelsea = $_POST['chelsea'];
if ($chelsea == 'chelsea_win') {
    $chelsea_score = $chelsea_score + 3;
    $chelsea_wins = $chelsea_wins + 1;
    $chelsea_played = $chelsea_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='chelsea_played', wins='chelsea_wins', points='chelsea_score' WHERE team = 'Chelsea'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();


}
elseif ($chelsea == 'chelsea_draw') {
    $chelsea_score = $chelsea_score + 1;
    $chelsea_draws = $chelsea_draws + 1;
    $chelsea_played = $chelsea_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='chelsea_played', draws='chelsea_draws', points='chelsea_score' WHERE team = 'Chelsea'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}
else {
    $chelsea_losses = $chelsea_losses + 1;
    $chelsea_played = $chelsea_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='chelsea_played', losses='chelsea_losses' WHERE team = 'Chelsea'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}

$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','pass','database');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bpl_teams WHERE team='Crystal Palace' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$crystalpalace_wins = $row['wins'];
$crystalpalace_draws = $row['draws'];
$crystalpalace_losses = $row['losses'];
$crystalpalace_score = $row['points'];
$crystalpalace_played = $row['played']; 

$crystalpalace = $_POST['crystalpalace'];
if ($crystalpalace == 'crystalpalace_win') {
    $crystalpalace_score = $crystalpalace_score + 3;
    $crystalpalace_wins = $crystalpalace_wins + 1;
    $crystalpalace_played = $crystalpalace_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='crystalpalace_played', wins='crystalpalace_wins', points='crystalpalace_score' WHERE team = 'Crystal Palace'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}
elseif ($crystalpalace == 'crystalpalace_draw') {
    $crystalpalace_score = $crystalpalace_score + 1;
    $crystalpalace_draws = $crystalpalace_draws + 1;
    $crystalpalace_played = $crystalpalace_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='crystalpalace_played', draws='crystalpalace_draws', points='crystalpalace_score' WHERE team = 'Crystal Palace'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();

}
else {
    $crystalpalace_losses = $crystalpalace_losses + 1;
    $crystalpalace_played = $crystalpalace_played + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='crystalpalace_played', losses='crystalpalace_losses' WHERE team = 'Crystal Palace'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_close();
}

?>
```

**NOTE:** I'm sure there is a much more efficient way of doing the above, but this works (mostly), so I'm not looking for advice on how to do this more efficiently.

So the question is why do only the first 3 rows update successfully?

Thanks in advance. Apologies for the mountains of code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand your question (I'm quite new to this), but that query runs successfully. I.E. I am able to get Arsenal's wins, losses, etc from the database with that query. The same applies to Aston Villa and Burnley, but the rest seem to fail for some reason. If I didn't manage to answer your question let me know and I'll try again...

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't scrolled down to read all the PHP code you had. Basically I was asking if when you run a query on the database to return all the rows (not just one) for a given team, what is returned? Do you get more than just 3 rows? Another user has also noticed you're connecting to two DB's, so I suspect there could be something else going on...

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this but the database table looks like this:
team   | played | wins | draws | losses | points |

Comment: You'll probably need a `while` loop to work in conjunction with `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` etc. So, has error reporting given you anything?

Comment: arsenal |  2    |    1    |   1   |    0     |    4  Would fall under those column headings respectively

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, error reporting gives me this: Warning: mysqli_close() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/daveg11/public_html/db_scores_bpl.php on line 26 | And then the same error every 40 lines from that one.

Comment: Change `mysqli_close()` to `mysqli_close($conn)` do it for all of them. A quick search and replace in your code editor, will fix that in 0.5 seconds flat ;-)

Comment: That got rid of all the errors, but still only the first 3 rows are updated.

Comment: ^ You still haven't answered my original question about how many rows are in your database that match your criteria... perhaps there's only three rows and you don't know it? PS, you're also not updating your Chelsea and Crystal Palace teams with the proper data, as you're missing $ on the variable names you intend to use. Any reason you're not typing those columns as integers instead of varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say when you say "first 3 rows" you actually mean first 3 teams...

In your Chelsea and Crystal Palace team logic blocks, your queries are missing variables in their SET assignments, so your data is being corrupted.

Any reason  you're not typing those columns as integers, rather than string/varchar?

Change your code for those teams to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$chelsea_played', wins='$chelsea_wins', points='$chelsea_score' WHERE team = 'Chelsea'";

$sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$chelsea_played', draws='$chelsea_draws', points='$chelsea_score' WHERE team = 'Chelsea'";

$sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$chelsea_played', losses='$chelsea_losses' WHERE team = 'Chelsea'";
```

and

```
$sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$crystalpalace_played', wins='$crystalpalace_wins', points='$crystalpalace_score' WHERE team = 'Crystal Palace'";

$sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$crystalpalace_played', draws='$crystalpalace_draws', points='$crystalpalace_score' WHERE team = 'Crystal Palace'";

$sql = "UPDATE bpl_teams SET played='$crystalpalace_played', losses='$crystalpalace_losses' WHERE team = 'Crystal Palace'";
```